# How to bring back the status bar when textfiled is tap?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have implemented

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

in my main function to hide the status bar but I need to bring it back when I tap on my Textfield. So the user can use the back option on the bottom bar.

I've tried to do this :

> onTap: () => SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays()

but that don't work.

```
Container _getSearchBar() {
    return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 21.0, right: 8.0, left: 8.0),
      child: new Card(
        child: new ListTile(
          leading: new Icon(Icons.search),
          title: new TextField(
            onTap: () => SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays(),
            controller: controller,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
          ),
          trailing: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.cancel),
            onPressed: () {
              controller.clear();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you share the code where you are calling `onTap()` ?

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

According to `restoreSystemUIOverlays()` function [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/restoreSystemUIOverlays.html) it only returns the last setting of `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays()` which is in your case hiding status bar. Instead you should use :

```
    onTap: () => SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
```

Comment: Thanks that work, sorry i don't check the official documentation, I only read posts about that.

Comment: I'm glad it helped